# c# wrapper class with enum property

Tags: c#, class, enums, wrapper

I have a class with Details with columnIndex

```
public class Details
{
    public int columnIndex { get; set;}
}
```

Then I have an enum.

```
public enum DetailsEnum
{
    Column1 = 1,
    Column2 = 2,
    Column3 = 3
}
```

Then I would like to create a wrapper class, that is using the enum above, with property

```
public class MyWrapperClass
{

  #region Fields

  private Details _details;

  #endregion

  #region Properties
public DetailsEnum sortColumnIndex
{
     get
     {

     }

     set
     {

     }
}
#endregion

}
```

I got stuck here and I was wondering what should I actually write in the get/set now? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to accomplish.  You can return the enum values, but how will you decide which one the `get` is to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enums can be cast to an int and vice versa.

```
public DetailsEnum sortColumnIndex
{
     get
     {
        return (DetailsEnum)  _details.columnIndex;
     }

     set { _details.columnIndex = (int)value;}
}
```

Comment: Ahaaa that was what I was trying to accomplish : ) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write anything. That would already work for your class

```
public class MyWrapperClass 
{
    private Details _details;

    public DetailsEnum sortColumnIndex { get; set; }
}
```

So, in a main method you could already use it.

```
public static void Main()
{
MyWrapperClass foo = new MyWrapperClass();
foo.sortColumnIndex =  DetailsEnum.Column1; // Set Property
Console.Write(foo.sortColumnIndex); // Column 1
Console.Write((int)foo.sortColumnIndex); // 1
}
```